# Bash interpreting increment operation as command

Tags: linux, bash

I'm trying to batch modify some images using a bash script, and to print out the progress. It looks to me like bash is interpreting the increment to counter as a command and is giving the following error:

```
augment_data.sh: line 20: 0: command not found
```

Here is the code:

```
for file in *.jpg
do
    convert $file -rotate 90 rotated_"$file"
    ((counter++))
    if $((counter % 10 == 0)); then
            echo "Rotated $counter files out of $num_files"
    fi
done
```

with line 20 being the one with the counter increment operation.

How can I fix this so that I don't get the error message?

Comment: whipe dollar sign after `if`!

Comment: use https://www.shellcheck.net/ it helps a lot in such cases

Comment: Thanks @F.Hauri, that did it! Could you please explain why I was getting an error and why it works now? Total bash noob here, but I want to learn.

Comment: `((...))` is a command; `$((...))` is an expression. Just like a parameter expansion, the *result* of the expression is used as the command to run as the `if` condition.

Comment: `(( counter % 10 == 0 ))` is the nicer way of writing `[[ $((counter % 10)) -eq 0 ]]`.

Comment: @chepner why is this nicer?

Comment: @ntj, ...shorter, easier for humans to read, doesn't mix multiple contexts unnecessarily?

Comment: @Charles Duffy Right, i didn't really notice that you don't have to use `-eq` there, etc. Good to know that.

Comment: BTW, make it `convert "$file"` with the quotes or you'll have bugs when processing filenames with spaces. I might consider using a preincrement rather than a postincrement, too -- `if (( ++counter % 10 == 0 ))` would mean you could ditch the `(( counter++ ))` line, and would make it one fewer place where `set -e` would break your script (see the first exercise under the allegory in [BashFAQ #105](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In an arithmetic substitution, *the result of an arithmetic operation* is substituted in the position of the operation itself.

In this case, `$(( 1 == 0 ))` has an arithmetic result of `0`, and `$(( 1 == 1 ))` has a result of `1`.

Thus, if you use `$(( ... ))`, then this `0` or `1` is substituted in that position, and so gets run as a command. Since you don't have commands named `0` or `1` (probably), either of these will result in a `command not found` error.

If you use `(( ... ))`, then the arithmetic result directly sets return value, but no expansion takes place.

Comment: Marked community wiki, since this is quite certainly a duplicate (but I haven't tracked it down yet). Folks here, feel free to edit for clarity/completeness/etc.